# Button disables itself in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Situation is simple: I have WPF UserControl of a WaitingBar
witch has binded visibility. So problem is 'CancelButton' is always disabled when Control is set to visible.
If i remove visibility binding control is always visible and button is enable.
In overview of Waitingbar.xaml button is also enabled.
What is wrong? Why button disables itself?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Neolant.Common.Ui.Wpf.Controls.WaitingBar"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:commonControls="clr-namespace:Neolant.Common.Ui.Wpf.Controls"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=commonControls:Waitor, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsWaiting, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
IsHitTestVisible="False" >

<Grid
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <!-- Фон -->
    <Rectangle 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Fill="LightGray" Opacity="0.5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <StackPanel
        Orientation="Vertical"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <!-- Анимация -->
        <Canvas
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="canvas"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Height="100" Width="100"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">

            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="rotation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:3" 
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotation" Angle="0"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        </Canvas>
        <!-- Текст -->
        <TextBlock 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{Binding Path=Text}"
            FontSize="20" 
            Foreground="SlateGray"
            Margin="5" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <!-- Прогресс бар-->
        <ProgressBar
            Grid.Row="2"
            Height="25"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="100"
            Name="pbMain" 
            Visibility="Hidden" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--Кнопка отмены-->
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        x:Name="CancelButton" 
        Style="{StaticResource ApplicationButtonStyle}" 
        Width="50" 
        Height="50"
        Margin="0,0,0,62"
        IsEnabled="True">
        <Path Data="{StaticResource CloseIconGeometry}" />
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Looking at code doesn't give any idea about the problem. But you can do one thing - Add debug point at set of public property which is bind to 'CancelButton'. And then see when and where that property is set false.

Comment: I'am actually kinda love this type of problems. It's like a murder investigation)

Comment: Then why ask for help? you're the only one that can fix it.

Comment: Sheridan, so from your point of view this site is pointless... But you wrong anyway. I can't fix this problem right now. I don't have required knowledge. And that is why I ask for help of anyone who maby had similar issue or already know what causes it.

Answer (score 2):

Ah... once again, somebody joins this website to ask yet another one of these questions that basically say '*Something in .NET doesn't work*'. Meanwhile the truth of *all* of these questions is that while a very few things in .NET *actually* don't work... we can pretty much rely on them all working for the vast majority of the time.

Therefore, your answer is the same as all those that asked similar questions here... the `Button` does *not* disable itself in the `UserControl` (unless you disable the `UserControl`), because they don't do that... the only possible answer is that YOU have disabled it. It's hard to show you your mistake because you haven't included all of your relevant code (but please don't add any more).

I can hazard a guess that perhaps, you have set its `IsEnabled` property to `false` in a `Loaded` event handler or something similar.  It can't be in the `ApplicationButtonStyle` because the setting the `IsEnabled` property to `true` on the `Button` would override that. If you have programmatically set the `Button.Command` property, then perhaps your `CanExecute` method is always returning `false`?

At the end of the day, this really is your mistake and your problem to fix. There is nothing that anybody here can do to help you with this further. You just need to look carefully through your project at what you do with this `Button` and at some stage, you'll find it. Just remember... `Button`s just don't disable themselves by default.

---

UPDATE >>>

Well, you say that you've '*tried all this and it did not help*', but as your problem still persists, you clearly haven't. I guarantee that it's your code that is disabling the `Button`. To prove this, just add another `Button`... clearly, it won't be disabled.

Try this instead... comment out the `Button` and try to build the project. If there are any references to the `Button` anywhere then you'll get an compilation error. If you get no compilation errors, then you probably have a parent container control with its `IsEditable` property set to `True`, thereby disabling all child controls.

Comment: And once again I get pretty default answer like "Your question is stupid" with pretty default suggestions and I tried all of this and it did not help. I know it's not magic. Basically my rebelious button have no code behind, no binding to command. nothing in my code touches this button. And even I add `CancelButton.IsEnabled=true` anywhere ... it's still remain disabled.

Comment: I'm having the exact issue OP describes. My button *is* enabled in the designer. Upon manually adding `IsEnabled="True"` the button within the design view becomes disabled. Likewise, if I move away from the XAML file and back to it, the enabled button is once again disabled. I'm starting with a completely fresh application so there's no code in place which automatically disables the control - the control is being disabled by Visual Studio prior to even running. Your answer doesn't help at all.

Comment: Im having the exact same issue. It seems at compiler time the button is being dissabled. Im using wpf toolkit's dropdownbutton. Any solution?